Little sister murders her older brother with firepoker, picks up his glasses from pool of blood and watches baseball
I remember I watched this movie/tv-movie/episode more or less 10 years ago on TV. My memory on this movie is very foggy since I watched it as a little kid and I only remember some details that maybe inaccurate, I think it's in black and white or at least not in technicolor since I remember it being dark. The story centers on three characters: the nanny, the older brother, and the little sister. Everyone turns out to be insane.
Plot: A nanny recently released from mental institution worked in a pretty big house. The older brother hates her but the little sister really likes her and often defends her when her brother bullies the nanny. The older brother hates the nanny because she was just released from mental institution and he thinks she's still crazy. The older brother usually threatened the nanny with a fire poker and sometimes hits her with it. The older brother loves baseball and he's only calm when he's watching baseball with headphones and I think his father (I think) threatens to removes all his baseball possession and his tv set if he keeps doing bad things to the nanny and he calms down a bit. He hates it when his sister or anyone near his tv set. The older brother did something resulting the nanny to be taken away to the mental institution again and the little girl cries begging her not to go.
Plot twist ending: The camera moves slowly showing the body of the older brother on the floor on a pool of blood. A fire poker he used to hit the nanny is right beside him. A hand shows picking his glasses from the pool of blood and turns out it's his little sister. She wears his glasses and put on the headphones to watch baseball quietly and calmly, shows that she's not the only normal or sane one because she kills her brother cold-bloodedly.
Characters appearance & characteristic (may not be accurate):

The nanny: Very weak, can't stand up for herself against the older brother. Blonde (I think). Often wears calf length skirt (I think). Very kind, nonthreatening. Only close to the little sister, often tries to shield the little sister from the older brother with her body taking his hits.
The older brother: Around 10, 12, 14 years old. Wears glasses. Appears to be a sociopath; he laughs hysterically after hitting and threatening the nanny with baseball bat or fire poker. Obsessed with baseball. Often wears flannel shirt (I think). He likes to swings fire poker or baseball bat around to scare the little sister and the nanny.
The little sister: Blonde (I think). Often wears shorts overalls. Around 6, 8 years old. Can stand up to her brother but overpowered by him. Really close to her nanny.


It sounds like the movie Twisted (1986) with Christian Slater. The film is based on Jack Horrigan's play, "Children! Children!" (IMDB)
Wikipedia:

One evening, the Collins family discovers their maid, Mrs. Murdock,
  dead at the end of their steps; her neck is broken. Evidently, she had
  an accident; now they need a new babysitter for an upcoming party. The
  sensible Helen meets little Susan Collins at the discount market and
  likes her, so she offers to do the job. She does not know Susan's
  teenage brother Mark(Christian Slater): technically skilled and good
  in school, but restive and cunning. Mark also listens regularly to
  German marching music from the Third Reich. As soon as the parents
  have left, he psychologically terrorizes Helen and his sister with
  electronic tricks. Williams (Karl Taylor), a school jock whom Mark
  burned earlier in science class, is out for revenge; Mark murders him
  with a fencing sword.
Ultimately, Mark himself is killed when Helen knocks him onto a spiked
  German helmet. Mark's parents come home to find the house in shambles;
  Evelyn puts the blame on Helen and tries to have her arrested, unaware
  that Mark lies dead upstairs. Phillip has already looked in their
  children's rooms, presumably finding Mark's body, but instead offers
  Helen a ride home. Helen simply turns down the offer and rides back
  home herself, with Phillip refusing to have her arrested immediately
  and suggesting they clean up the house. Secretly, Susan dons her late
  brother's glasses and proceeds to listen to his Nazi music and the
  cycle begins anew.

allmovie:

When his bickering parents (Tandy Cronyn, Dan Ziskie) attend a party
  at a local country club, Mark and his sister (Brooke Tracy) are left
  in the care of a local socialite (Lois Smith) with a history of mental
  disturbances. That's when Mark decides to unleash his nasty bag of
  psychological tricks, attempting to frighten the poor woman into a
  mental collapse.




Movie Twisted (1986)

wow i was way off haha but thank you so much!!!! I've been looking for this movie for ages! Thanks!

If this helped, feel free to click the checkmark so you can accept the answer and give each other some rep :) welcome to the site.

@KayThxBye .....................
